# help showing a simple asymptotic relation?

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

The solution to the Landau equation

$$\frac{d \vert A\rvert^2}{d t}=2\sigma \lvert A \rvert^2-l \lvert A \rvert^4$$

is

$$\lvert A \rvert ^2= \frac{A_0^2}{{\frac{l}{2\sigma} A_0^2+\left(1-\frac{l}{2 \sigma} A_0^2 \right) e^{-2\sigma t} }},$$
where $l$ and $\sigma$ are constant, $A_0$ is the initial value of $\lvert A \rvert$.

If $l>0$ and $\sigma>0$, the textbook showed that the above solution gives

$$\lvert A \rvert \sim A_0 e^{\sigma t}$$ as $t\to-\infty$ and $A_0\to 0$. But I think simply
$$\lim _{t \to -\infty , A_0 \to 0} \lvert A \rvert ^2=\frac{0}{\infty}=0$$

Can anybody suggest me how to show this asymptotic relation? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
\lvert A \rvert ^2 &=& \frac{A_0^2}{{\frac{l}{2\sigma} A_0^2+\left(1-\frac{l}{2 \sigma} A_0^2 \right) e^{-2\sigma t} }}\\
&=& \frac{A_0^2e^{2\sigma t}}{{\frac{l}{2\sigma} A_0^2e^{2\sigma t}+\left(1-\frac{l}{2 \sigma} A_0^2 \right) }}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{\lvert A \rvert ^2}{e^{2\sigma t}} 
&=& \lim_{t\to-\infty}\frac{A_0^2}{{\frac{l}{2\sigma} A_0^2e^{2\sigma t}+\left(1-\frac{l}{2 \sigma} A_0^2 \right) }}=A_0^2.
\end{eqnarray}
So $|A|\sim A_0e^{\sigma t}$ as $t\to-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you @xpaul. But $A_0\to 0$ at the same time. How do we have the second equality in the last expression? As we known, $f(x) \sim 0$ as $x \to 0$ is WRONG. (Nothing is ever asymptotic to zero.)

Comment: I forgot that you ask for $A_0\to0$ too.